# Support for JsonRequest please

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have the following json:

```
 {
     "code": "1",
     "status": "OK",
     "users": [
         {
             "id": "5",
             "yazi": "launcher",
             "gun": "2015-08-04"
         },
         {
             "id": "6",
             "yazi": "piano",
             "gun": "2015-02-02"
         },
         {
             "id": "9",
             "yazi": "text text",
             "gun": "2015-08-05"
         },
         {
             "id": "14",
             "yazi": null
             "gun": "2015-02-02"
         }
     ] }
```

i want to if code is "1" and status is "OK" then view users parameter.
What should I used?

Comment: Check this for json parsing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    String status=obj.getString("status");
    String code=obj.getString("code");
    if(code.equalsIgnoreCase("1") && status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK"))
    {
         JSONArray users = object.getJSONArray("users");   for(int i=0;i<jusers.length;i++) {JsonObject jsonObj=users.getJsonObject(i). String id=jsonObj.getString("id");
    }                                                                                                             pass other data the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to parse a `JSONObject`:

```
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    String code = object.optString("code");
    String status = object.optString("status");
    if (code.equals("1") && status.equals("OK")) {
        JSONArray users = object.getJSONArray("users");
        // do your code 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
    String status=obj.getString("status");
    String code=obj.getString("code");
    if(code.equalsIgnoreCase("1") && status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK"))
    {
        //Parse your users array
    }
```

Comment: how I parse users array?